# Do I need all permission for an applet that reads and writes to my own server

Tags: java, applet, manifest

I have an applet the reads and writes files from and to my own server. Basically, image the applet is a text editor that allows users to write simple texts, then click save. When they click save, the data is sent to my server. When they click open, the data is loaded into the applet from my server. They are allowed to name each file they save so they can open it back. But all of this communication is between the applet and my server. So in my manifest, is it ok to have

```
Permissions: sandbox
```

Or should I change to

```
Permissions: all-permissions
```

Comment: Technically, the applet is actually reading or writing anything to your server, as the applet executes with the local context of the client PC.  I assume that the applet is capable of opening some kind of connection back to your server in order to facilitate the reading/writing process, like a `Socket` or `URL` connection for example.  In which case you may need permissions to open a network connection, although from memory, opening a connection to the same domain context that the applet was loading from doesn't require any special privileges, but you would need to test this

Answer (score 0):

> I have an applet the reads and writes files from and to my own server.

1. No app. can directly write files to a server.  If it were psossible, the server would be inundated with images of child pornography within 24 hours.
2. Instead, the server must offer some functionality to accept an upload, and take actions of its own to store the data.
3. An applet can 'phone home' to its own server's 'resource save/restore functionality' while sand-boxed.